# An equivalent condition for the surjectivity of the differential of a map .

Tags: real-analysis

Let f be a differentiable map from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^p$ $f=(f_1,\ldots,f_p)$ $p\leq n$.
Im trying to show that
$df(a)$ is surjective if and only if the family of linear forms $\{d(f_i)(a)\}_{i=1}^p$ is free in $(\mathbb{R}^n)^*$.

I know that f is differentiable if and only if all the $f_i$ are, and $df=(df_1,\ldots,df_p)$, but what next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $df(a):\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^p$ is a linear map of vector spaces (more precisely, the tangent spaces at $a$ and $f(a)$), it is surjective if and only if it has rank $p$ (full rank). That is, if you fix bases on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}^p$, and then represent $df(a)$ as an $p \times n$ matrix, each of the $p$ rows (corresponding to the coordinate functions $df_i(a), 1 \leq i \leq p$) are linearly independent. As each such function is an element of $(\mathbb{R}^n)^*$, one sees that they are linearly independent forms iff $df(a)$ is surjective, i.e., $f$ has rank $p$ at $a$.

Comment: thank you sir for your response.
 You've been very helpful, but one thing is still unclear : the relation between the rows of the matrix representing $df(a)$ and the family $\{d(f_i)(a)\}_{i=1}^p$.
 Here is what i think : the map $\phi:(\mathbb{R}^n)^*\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$
 $\phi(g)=(g(e_1),\ldots,g(e_n))$ is an isomorphism and since $\phi(d(f_i)(a))=(d(f_i)(a)(e_1),\ldots,d(f_i)(a)(e_n))=(\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_1}(a),\ldots,\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_n}(a))$ which is a row of the matrix then the family $\{d(f_i)(a)\}_{i=1}^p$ is free iff the family of the rows is.

Comment: That’s right. Since the rows of the differential are linear maps from $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$, they are elements of $(\mathbb{R}^n)^*$ by definition. Since they also produce the coordinate-wise output of the differential, they can be identified with its coordinate functions $df_i(a)$ (which is what you wrote in detail).

Comment: thank you such much sir.